# How to check the validity of this argument using the rules of inference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I have this argument :

1. I play basketball and football.
2. If today isn't Saturday, then I play basketball and football.
3. If today is Friday OR today is Saturday, then I don't play football.
4. Therefore, I don't play football.

Let p = "I play football".
Let q = "I play basketball".
Let s = "Today is Saturday".
Let f = "Today is Friday".

1. p ∩ q .
2. ∼s → (p ∩ q) .
3. (f ∪ s) → ∼q .
4. ∴ ∼q

I made the truth table : 
http://jan.imghost.us/yiCV.jpg

I need now to check the validity of this argument using the rules of inference. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your truth table shows that the argument isn't valid (the assignment of values $p \Rightarrow T$, $q \Rightarrow T$, $f \Rightarrow F$,  $s \Rightarrow F$ makes the premisses true and conclusion false).

So you now know that, in your favourite sound deductive system for propositional logic (whatever that is), there is no way of getting from the premisses to the conclusion by the rules of inferences. So you know you *can't* "check the validity ... using rules of inference" if that means producing a derivation of the conclusion from the premisses.

Comment: ...you said pretty much what I would have said! +1 and Happy New Year, Peter!

Comment: In this particular case, wouldn't it suffice to simply state that if the conclusion was true, then we would have both q from (1) and ~q, a contradiction?